# Why is the connection to my localhost TLS server failing?

Tags: go, ssl, curl, openssl, x509

I have a locally generated X.509 certificate (i.e. CA certificate) and private key. The "CA" certificate is used to sign client certificates. It is also used as the server certificate for a HTTP+TLS web server running on localhost.

Clients get certificates signed by the CA certificate and attempt to connect to the HTTP+TLS web server by presenting their new certificates. Go clients are set up with a root trust pool consisting only of the CA certificate. The server has its client trust root also set to the CA certificate in Go.

CA Certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The server is written in Go1.21. It is set up to trust client certificates signed by the CA certificate. I tried a Go client and curl. The Go client is set up with a certificate trust pool consisting of only the CA certificate. The curl client was not set up with this trust pool, but I had turned off verification with `-k`.

The TLS web server is set up like so:

```golang
// cert is a tls.Certificate containing the CA certificate
// clientCertPool is a certificate pool containing the CA certificate too
server := http.Server{
        Handler: hdlr,
        Addr:    addr,
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
            ClientAuth:   tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
            ClientCAs:    clientCertPool,
            KeyLogWriter: ssllog,
        },
    }
```

And this is the client:

```golang
func HTTPClient(clientCert tls.Certificate, roots *x509.CertPool, ssllog io.Writer) *http.Client {
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{clientCert},
        RootCAs:      roots,
        KeyLogWriter: ssllog,
    }
    tlsTransport := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
    tlsTransport.TLSClientConfig = tlsConfig

    return &http.Client{
        Transport: tlsTransport,
    }
}
```

### Errors

When Go client connects to the TLS server, I see the following errors:

Go Client: `Get \"https://localhost:8443/v1/description\": remote error: tls: internal error`

TLS Server: `http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:55740: invalid argument`

And when curl connects to the TLS server, I see this instead.

Curl: `curl: (35) LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404B438:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert internal error`

TLS Server: `http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:55792: invalid argument`

The error reported by the server is the same both times. The confusing part for me is that this setup used to work a month ago. Only the CA certificate might have changed slightly, but everything else is the same.

I can share more code if necessary. I can also capture wireshark traces if that would help.

The code for the [CA server](https://github.com/RealImage/bifrost/blob/fbd25c199b567318933ec862dd245c1927fa23e2/cmd/issuer/main.go) and the [TLS web server](https://github.com/RealImage/bifrost/blob/fbd25c199b567318933ec862dd245c1927fa23e2/cmd/bouncer/main.go#L80C2-L89C3) are open-source and available at https://github.com/RealImage/bifrost.

Comment: So you are trying to simultaneously use a self-signed CA certificate as both a TLS server certificate *and* in its traditional role as a signer of other certificates?

Comment: Yep that's the gist of it.

Comment: "Only the CA certificate might have changed slightly" such as how?

Comment: I added a subject alternative name extension containing localhost. Nothing else changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your certificate is missing pretty much all of the required extensions per RFC 5280 for use as a TLS server certificate.

[For example](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3):

> 4.2.1.3.  Key Usage
>
> The key usage extension defines the purpose (e.g., encipherment,
> signature, certificate signing) of the key contained in the
> certificate.  The usage restriction might be employed when a key that
> could be used for more than one operation is to be restricted.  For
> example, when an RSA key should be used only to verify signatures on
> objects other than public key certificates and CRLs, the
> digitalSignature and/or nonRepudiation bits would be asserted.
> Likewise, when an RSA key should be used only for key management, the
> keyEncipherment bit would be asserted.
>
> Conforming CAs MUST include this extension in certificates that
> contain public keys that are used to validate digital signatures on
> other public key certificates or CRLs

Note the use of "MUST".  There are many other extensions your certificate lacks.

This is the text description of your certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            4f:6b:31:b6:90:3d:93:55:55:75:bf:c3:49:52:04:de:86:00:35:ff
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: CN = 6b90cabc-e6aa-560a-b5c3-81feeb14de50, O = 91bc0ae8-1307-4f13-80e4-cef468160142
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 28 06:26:28 2023 GMT
            Not After : Sep 25 06:26:28 2033 GMT
        Subject: CN = 6b90cabc-e6aa-560a-b5c3-81feeb14de50, O = 91bc0ae8-1307-4f13-80e4-cef468160142
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:13:76:41:49:7b:8f:37:f1:92:15:ff:84:e6:7e:
                    b8:56:db:f9:37:1f:a9:d4:f3:80:84:11:66:b1:63:
                    6b:24:90:bd:0d:a3:7b:c3:1b:30:e1:01:d7:18:c8:
                    49:77:7b:9b:83:be:7c:e8:c7:bd:d2:a0:3f:e5:d0:
                    8c:ec:1c:b5:b7
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                CA:2F:94:0D:43:FB:6D:00:66:09:50:4C:8C:1F:A3:BC:C1:EF:98:F4
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:CA:2F:94:0D:43:FB:6D:00:66:09:50:4C:8C:1F:A3:BC:C1:EF:98:F4
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:44:02:20:70:13:f4:54:d4:1a:73:9e:61:4b:fc:91:b4:4e:
         3b:23:08:89:a5:a8:20:c4:7b:1b:de:18:2d:58:46:bf:22:32:
         02:20:1e:da:af:d2:be:43:61:03:a3:da:50:61:50:5c:be:02:
         0c:50:83:5b:83:97:08:f6:ed:27:50:14:44:f4:d9:d5
```

That is going to fail validation as a TLS server certificate in multiple ways:

1. There are no [Subject Alternative Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) that identify the TLS server it's being used for.
2. The certificate does not have the other [Basic Constraints](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_certificate_system/9/html/administration_guide/standard_x.509_v3_certificate_extensions) for TLS server key usage such as `keyEncipherment` nor for it's use as a CA certificate such as `CASigning`.
3. The certificate is missing [Extended Key Usage](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_certificate_system/9/html/administration_guide/standard_x.509_v3_certificate_extensions#Discussion-PKIX_Extended_Key_Usage_Extension_Uses) attributes that directly identify it as a TLS server certificate = `serverAuth`.

I suspect your client certificates are also missing the necessary X509 extensions for use as a client certificate.

And did you know your old client certificates signed by your previous CA cert are useless with the new CA cert?  The only way they can work is if you add your old certificate to your server's set of trusted CA certificates, and that's assuming your old certificate isn't expired.

Also, see [OpenSSL's `x509v3_config` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/x509v3_config.html):

> **x509v3_config**
>
> **NAME**
>
> x509v3_config - X509 V3 certificate extension configuration format
> DESCRIPTION
>
> Several of the OpenSSL utilities can add extensions to a certificate
> or certificate request based on the contents of a configuration file.
>
> .
> .
> .

Comment: I'll look into adding the required extensions to my TLS server certificate. It looks like I won't be able to use the same certificate as a CA signing certificate and a TLS web server certificate.

Why do you "suspect" aspects of my client certificates instead of, you know asking for the exact details? And, yes, I do know that certificates signed by one certificate won't work when verified against another.

Comment: @Ananth If you missed the required extensions for a server and a CA certificate, there's a good chance you missed them for the client certificates, too.  `openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text` will show you the cert in text form.